# Counter strike condition zero - How to get current position/coordinate

Tags: counter-strike-condition-zero

I check around the internet, they said to get the position in counter strike 1.6, use the console command:

> cl_showpos 1

But this command is not working for Counter strike: Condition zero. So how to get current coordinate in Counter strike: Condition zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're wrong. `cl_showpos` is for CS Source and Global Offensive and doesn't work in 1.6 either.

To get your current position in 1.6 and Condition Zero you can use the `status` command.
The upper part of it contains your location:

> ] status
>   hostname:  Condition Zero
>   version :  48/1.0.0.3/Stdio 7561 insecure  (80)
>   tcp/ip  :  192.168.20.103:27015
>   **map   :  de_nuke at: 3072 x, -479 y, -298 z**
>   players :  1 active (32 max)